# Adaptive Particle Filter: unknown process Equation

Tags: signal-processing, programming, digital-filter

In my design and implementation of a SIR particle Filter, I don't have the state process equation of the actual system, which would have given a very good estimation of the real signal. I was wondering, if there are any mathematical methods out there to extrapolate the next state (i.e construction of process equation) based on the given previous estimates and measurements. I would also add that I am using this filter for a real-time application, which is subject to continous random change. That makes the filter an adaptive particle filter according to my understanding of the terms.

I have tried to extrapolate using a set of previous measurements, but the estimate was just as the meausrements, namely noisy, amplified and shifted by an offset. It does not make any sense obviously, since the filter is intended to correct these measurement uncertainties.

Any promising suggestions would help!

Comment: This might be better posted in the Signal Processing forum.

Comment: Sounds like a Kalman would do the job, but I agree with @SteveSh.

Comment: Particle Filter is  a more generlized approach of the family of bayesian filters, to which the Kalman Filter belongs.